# Regular Expression - match

Tags: javascript, regex, backbone.js

**EDIT:** I probably should have mentioned that this is for a Backbone.js route. Splitting it is not an option.

With the following string:

```
!/example/c/0/0/0/0
```

I am trying to use "match()" to extract the values between the slashes. My issue is that the last item("/0") may not always be in the string. This is what I currently have:

```
'!/example/c/0/0/0/0'.match(/^!(\/[A-z0-9\-_]+|)\/c\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+)\/([0-9]+/)
```

This returns an array with 'example', '0', '0', '0' if example is present and '', '0', '0', '0' if example is not present... So in the end the result I would like to see is:

```
'example', '0', '0', '0', ''
```

when the last item isn't present or:

```
'example', '0', '0', '0', '0'
```

when it is present. So basically it's the slash before the last item that's getting me! Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why are you trying to do this with a regular expression? You know what your delimiter is, so `split` the string and be done with it.

Comment: Added more info... I can't split it because it's a Backbone.js Route

Comment: I don't understand the connection between "Backbone route" and "cannot use `split`". Can you clarify what's going on with a bit more code?

Comment: @muistooshort - A Backbone route basically maps a hashtag(#!/example/c/0/0/0/0 - in this case) to a method. So for example: "this.route(/regex_here/, 'method_name');" - each segment in the url is passed as a param to the mapped method. So you see, without modifying Backbone, I can not use split.

Comment: So you're manually adding a Backbone route using [`r.route`](http://backbonejs.org/#Router-route) and you're building the regex yourself rather than using Backbone's route-string-to-regex mangler?

Comment: @muistooshort yes- i'm building it myself...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Prefer splitting because you know your delimiter, this will be easier !

```
var toSplit = "!/example/c/0/0/0/0";
var splitted = toSplit.split('/');
```

Comment: I probably should have been more clear... It's a Backbone.js route. So I can't split it.

Answer (score 1):

The `.split()` function will probably be sufficient for what you are trying to do, but the regular expression you are looking for is as follows:

```
/^!\/([A-z0-9\-_]+)\/c\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d*)/

'!/example/c/0/0/0/'.match(/^!\/([A-z0-9\-_]+)\/c\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d*)/)
["!/example/c/0/0/0/", "example", "0", "0", "0", ""]

'!/example/c/0/0/0/0'.match(/^!\/([A-z0-9\-_]+)\/c\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d+)\/(\d*)/)
["!/example/c/0/0/0/0", "example", "0", "0", "0", "0"]
```

`\d` is a shortcut for `[0-9]`, and `*` means *repeat 0 or more times*, while `+` means *repeat 1 or more times.*

Answer (score 1):

You if you don't need a strict check about the values, you can have something like that:

```
"!/example/c/0/0/0/0".match(/^!\/([^/]+)\/c\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([^/]+)\/([^/]*)/);
```

Keep in mind that you have no way as far as I know to have the exact array you're looking for using only `match`: The first element of the array is the whole matched string, not "example".